# Equivalent of Zope ExternalEditor for Django

Tags: django, textbox, editor, django-admin, zope

The [ExternalEditor](http://www.plope.com/software/ExternalEditor) is a Zope product and configurable helper application that allows you to drop into your favorite editor(s) directly from the ZMI to modify Zope objects.

I'd like to obtain the same editor integration in Django admin forms (textareas) and I'm wondering if something like that exist for Django too.

Any hint? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ExternalEditor did some clever Zope integration, but if all you really want is to edit text areas using your favourite editor (EMACS!!!) then maybe all you need is a browser plugin:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/its-all-text/

looks like it does it.